# Convert comma delimited string into YAML structure and merge into existing YAML

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have already existing YAML file:

```
a:
  b:
    c:
      d: "val1"
      e: "val2"
      f: "val3"
```

I need to take following string:

`a.b.c.x.val4`

and merge it into existing yaml dynamically.

So first step is to load file into YAML object which I did, but I now I need a way to dynamically be able to extend it.

If I would have constant number of input parts, then it would be easy:

`data["a"]["b"]["c"]["x"]="val4"`, but need to do it dynamically since input size is not constant.

I am thinking to first convert this input to separate yaml and then merge two yamls, but here not clear how to dynamically create yaml from such input. If I do it like below, I just create a map:

```
arr="a.b.c.x.val4".split["."]
for i in 0..2 do
  b[arr[i]]=arr[i+1]
end
```

What is the best way to do it?

Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have access to other libraries and not using Rails so I did this manually:

```
    #result of merging existing yaml and the one we add will be in this var
    result_props={}

    prop_name="a.b.c.d"
    parts=prop_name.split(".")

    #new_prop is yaml object created from a.b.c.d
    new_prop={}
    new_prop[parts[parts.length-1]]="value"
    for i in (parts.length-2).downto(0)
      new_part={}
      new_part[parts[i]]=new_prop
      new_prop=new_part
    end

    #props_file_path is a file with already existing yaml into which I'm merging a.b.c.d="value"    
    if !File.file? props_file_path
      result_props=new_prop
    else
      yaml_string = File.read props_file_path
      existing_yaml_props=YAML.load yaml_string
      result_props=existing_yaml_props

      for i in 0..parts.length-1
        if existing_yaml_props[parts[i]] == nil
          existing_yaml_props[parts[i]]=new_prop[parts[i]]
          break
        else
          existing_yaml_props=existing_yaml_props[parts[i]]
          new_prop=new_prop[parts[i]]
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [DeepMerge](https://github.com/hashie/hashie#deepmerge) from the [hashie](https://github.com/hashie/hashie) gem in order to combine two deeply nested hashes together.

Right after that, you should convert the resulting hash back to the YAML format.

Here is an example:

```rb
class MyHash < Hash
  include Hashie::Extensions::DeepMerge
end

h1 = MyHash[{ 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => { 'd' => 'val1', 'e' => 'val2', 'f' => 'val3' } } } }]
h2 = MyHash[{ 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => { 'x' => 'val4' } } } }]

h1.deep_merge(h2)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>"val1", "e"=>"val2", "f"=>"val3", "x"=>"val4"}}}}
```

---

If you are using [Rails](https://rubyonrails.org/) (or [stand-alone ActiveSupport](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support)), then [Hash#deep_merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge) from [Extensions to Hash](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-hash) is the other way which can help to solve your problem:

```rb
h1 = { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => { 'd' => 'val1', 'e' => 'val2', 'f' =>  'val3' } } } }
h2 = { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => { 'x' => 'val4' } } } }

h1.deep_merge(h2)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>"val1", "e"=>"val2", "f"=>"val3", "x"=>"val4"}}}}
```

---

In order to generate the `h2` hash with the dynamic length of the key, I suggest trying the [rodash](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash) gem, its [set](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash#rodashset-example) method if to be more precise.

```rb
*key, value = 'a.b.c.x.val4'.split('.')

key
# => ["a", "b", "c", "x"]

value
# => "val4"

h2 = {}

Rodash.set(h2, key, value)

h2
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"x"=>"val4"}}}}
```

Here are the links to docs of [Multiple Assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) and [Array Decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) (techniques that what used to get `key` and `value` variables).